# /var/libs/mysql is too full

Tags: mysql

hey, i have written php script and it frozen mysql and when i restarted my linux (debian) there was something written that `/var/libs/mysql is too full`
and now when i want to run mysql there is an error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free up some disk space and try again?  You are going to need to do some investigating on your own about what you choose to delete.  I don't know how you have setup your partitions.  If /var/log is on the same partition as /var/lib then I would be tempted to delete/compress/move some of the older log files to get your system working again.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
df -h
```

This will see how much free space you have available.  Sounds like your /var partition filled up.  You may want to look at cleaning files up, quite possibly logfiles at /var/log.